How to prevent duplication and/or missing icon of Adobe Acrobat Reader tabs in Windows taskbar?
I open a pdf document and it initially has only one tab in the Windows taskbar:

But when I switch between desktops and come back to the desktop where the window is open, there is now two tabs with the pdf open:

And only one of them (the left one) works to open the window. And, sometimes, the icon is not visible despite the label name appearing (icons from other apps become invisible too; see my related question Why Windows 11 taskbar tabs have visualization problems when switching desktops?)
In another similar example, I had 2 pdfs open, but 3 tabs in the taskbar (and again, only the leftmost taskbar tab works)

When I check the taskbar, there are only 2 processes, as it should:

And when I close Adobe Acrobat Reader (AAR), these processes disappear.
But if I have only one tab open, I see two Acrobat.exe processes:

Current remediation that works: restart the windows explorer process at the task manager. After that, I have no duplicate tab anymore, and, if any icons weren't visible, they become visible again.
Is there any way to fix this so that it is always one tab and all icons are visible?

I am using the following software versions:

Windows 11 version 23H2 22631.4037
Adobe Acrobat Reader 2024.002.21005

The Windows taskbar settings I am using are:

Taskbar alignment: "Left"
Show badges on taskbar apps: Active
Show flashing on taskbar apps: Active
Share any window from my taskbar: Active
Select the far corner of the taskbar to show the desktop: Active
Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels: "When taskbar is full"
Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels on other taskbars: "When taskbar is full"

Other interesting related behaviors:

I can move the tabs from one desktop to another (and the duplication problem persists in the desktop to which the tabs are moved)
I can separate the pdf tabs into two AAR windows and then move each window to a separate desktop. Then I have a N taskbar tabs in each desktop, even if the window actually only has one pdf (N is the number of total pdfs open).
when I open a pdf on another desktop, Windows automatically switches to the desktop where the other pdfs are open. If there are multiple windows, it opens the new pdf in one of them (I don't know if there is a consistent behavior for which)
sometimes when I switch desktops the taskbar tabs are all messy (icons missing, text overlaying over one another:

but in this case, it is then back to normal when I simply click anywhere in the taskbar. In this example, there were no Adobe Acrobat Reader tabs open in the desktop where the problem happened, but if I switch desktops I see the same mess of several tabs overlaid in any desktop, even if that desktop only has one tab. Again, when I click, everything looks ok.


I can reproduce this issue on Windows 11 23H2 22631.4037 and Acrobat Pro x64 2024.002.20991 with only one instance of Acrobat.exe running. It will actually show N+1 taskbar buttons when you have N documents open in Acrobat, it's not limited to 2. Seems like an Acrobat bug, and despite not appearing in the list of known issues, there are plenty of longstanding Acrobat issues that haven't been fixed or added to that list.

I have created a related question about taskbar missing icons in Windows: https://superuser.com/questions/1853264/why-windows-11-taskbar-tabs-have-visualization-problems-when-switching-desktops

@KJ I do have 2 Acrobat.exe processes running even after closing all Adobe Acrobat Reader windows. I don't know if there is one that is a ghost of another. Does this information help in any way?

@HomeroEsmeraldo Other (free) PDF readers are available, if that's an option.

I know. But I like Adobe Acrobat Reader annotation feature better than the other ones I tried.

@KJ You have that multiple process problem with Sumatra? You mean double click on SumatraPDF application/shortcut, right? And then opening it again through opening a specific pdf. In my case, I don't open the sessions in separate desktops, it was all just in one desktop. I switched to another desktop where other applications were open (Chrome, Spotify). I don't understand your mention to "red/yellow/green bottle hanging on the wall".

Hi, @KJ, thanks for the comments. I added information about the taskbar setting I am using, and about the behaviors you described. Let me know if you have any other ideas of what to explore or test.

As I added in the post: my Adobe Acrobat Reader does move to any desktop I move it to. So that's different from your description.

I don't know what happened last time I checked. When I test now closing the pdfs, the Acrobat.exe processes are not there anymore. I also added this to the question.
