Why Windows 11 taskbar tabs have visualization problems (icon missing/duplicate tab) when switching desktops?
I would like to know what is causing some icons to not show up in my Windows taskbar sometimes and to have duplicate Adobe Acrobat Reader tabs.
In the image below, the file named "2024-04-..." is a Powerpoint window. The tab "swr repla" is a Zotero tab.

When I switch to a different Windows virtual desktop and come back to the initial virtual desktop, the visualization problem switches tabs. Now a Word tab doesn't show its icon anymore (and the Zotero icon in tab "swr replay" is visible again):

In this case, both Powerpoint tabs ("2024-04-..." and "cognitive_...") work appropriately when I click on them, regardless of the taskbar visualization working or not (in a related duplicate Adobe Acrobat tab problem linked below, the duplicate tab does not work).
Temporary/remediation solution: restart windows explorer process in the taskbar. After restart, the tabs are all visible and working appropriately again. But soon enough the problem happens again. The trigger is not consistent. Sometimes I switch desktops and the visualization works fine, sometimes it triggers the problem.
Any clues of how to fix or at least ideas of where to look to find the cause of the problem?
Related questions/solutions online:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/16cfklg/icons_disappeared_from_the_taskbar/
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/some-taskbar-icons-are-missing/a192192b-85f3-47f9-bcab-48b40e8f8bcb?page=1

But they do not explain what causes the problem nor how to prevent it from happening. The suggestions alternative to restarting windows explorer process (try new windows user, rebuild icon library, use chkdsk, etc) are all to remediate, not to prevent. I have seen this problem even after I switched users in Windows. As I already have a temporary/remediation solution (restart windows explorer), I have not tried the other solutions offered there.
I suspect that the problem may be caused by Adobe Acrobat Reader (AAR) (see more details in question How to prevent duplication and/or missing icon of Adobe Acrobat Reader tabs in Windows taskbar?)
Some pdfs are open in AAR. Inspecting Task Manager, I see processes named Acrobat.exe and AcroCEF.exe. Not sure if the Adobe processes could be affecting the rest of the system.

If a taskbar icon is not showing up, closing all open windows of AAR will not solve it.
I have also seen the problem happen after all AAR windows had been closed (but there were remaining Acrobat processes running).

It might be unrelated to AAR, but I don't know. The problem is not always present, so I have not yet seen if it can happen if AAR was never run since the computer was turned on.

I am using an external display. If I already have the problem and then disconnect the external monitor, the problem persists. I have not yet tested if the problem happens if I don't use an external monitor since system startup.
I am using the following software versions:

Windows 11 version 23H2 22631.4037
Adobe Acrobat Reader 2024.002.21005

The Windows taskbar settings I am using are:

Taskbar alignment: "Left"
Show badges on taskbar apps: Active
Show flashing on taskbar apps: Active
Share any window from my taskbar: Active
Select the far corner of the taskbar to show the desktop: Active
Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels: "When taskbar is full"
Combine taskbar buttons and hide labels on other taskbars: "When taskbar is full"


By "switching desktops", I assume you mean virtual desktops? Does this affect all applications? What happens if you move the affected application to another/new desktop (and back)?

What have you tried so far to solve this problem? What is your Windows version? What are the versions of the affected applications? Did you check for any known issues for Windows (e.g. 23H2) and the affected application? Is your Windows version up to date? Are the affected applications up to date? What does this problem have to do with Acrobat (see question tags)?

Thanks, @Albin. I edited my question and added the Windows and Adobe Acrobat Reader versions. The reason I included Adobe Acrobat in the tags is because of suspicion that it may be causing the issues in the taskbar (but I'm not sure). I've clarified that in the question. No known issues listed about this problem. Virtual desktop, yes (clarified in the question). Hope that clarifies. Do you have any idea of what the problem is?

@HomeroEsmeraldo - I am unable to reproduce the behavior, so can you reproduce the behavior, if you avoid having Adobe Acrobat running?

As I mentioned, the problem is not triggered every time I switch desktops. I have tried with and without Adobe open over the last few days, but the problem has not happened again. But, given the my experience with this, soon enough it will happen again.

@HomeroEsmeraldo What exactly is open, Adobe Acrobat or Acrobat Reader? Does the problem also occur if you don't have Acrobat/Reader open? There are solutions/suggestions posted under your like rebuilding the icon library, using a new user, using chkdsk etc. Which ones have you tried so far? Did, you check for any updates you can install for any of the apps (or for Windows, although I think it's the latest version, but please check anyway)?

@Albin Adobe Acrobat Reader. The problem of having a taskbar icon not show can happen when Adobe Acrobat Reader (AAR) is not open anymore. I.e. if a taskbar icon was not showing, closing AAR will not solve it. It might well be unrelated to AAR, but I don't know. Because the problem is not always present, I have not yet seen if it can happen if AAR was never run since the computer was turned on.

@Albin I have not tried the solutions linked in the URL I posted because the users there say the solution is temporary. I already have a temporary solution: restarting windows explorer. I would like to know what is causing this problem and if there is a permanent fix. The searches I made did not mention any help with any updates. In any case Windows 23H2 is the latest, so is AAR.

I have now added the names of the Adobe processes to the text of the question. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

@HomeroEsmeraldo you might have found a workaround but haven't isolated the problem yet. The suggestions from your links give you examples of how to approach the issue the rest is common sense. This will be the first step: to find the cause, everything else is just poking around in the dark. As Ramhound already mentioned there is not enough information to reproduce the behavior.

That's exactly the point of this question: I don't know how to find the cause, much less the solution. The URLs point to temporary solutions, I was wishing someone here would guide me to find the cause. What other information should I add so that the community can help me find the cause of the problem, and, potentially, the solution?
